# Get The Audio File using ibm-watson-speech-to-text

Tags: ibm-watson

i am using ibm watson-speech-to-text.

i am getting the text  output related to the audio.

My question is is it possible to get the audio file from it ?

Here my code

```
var recognizeMic = require('watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize- 
 microphone')

var stream = recognizeMic({
  access_token: this.state.watsonAccessToken,
  outputElement: '#output',  
})
  stream.on('data', async (data: any) => {
  this.state.recognizedText= data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
  }
```

can anyone help me how i get the speech ?

Comment: The `data` this is being input into your arrow function is the raw audio. What do you want to do with it? play it? store it into a file? You can do either, but you will also need to listen for something like `stream.on('end' ...`

Comment: thank you for your replay.  I want to store the audio  into a file .. How  its possible ? can you share  more data..